# Define SceneKit Measurement Units

Tags: scenekit

I know sceneKit measurement units are arbitrary but I don't know how I can set the sceneKit measurement unit to be in Meters where each unit equals 1 mm.

I have an AR library that returns in MM and I need to show that position in my live camera feed.

Appreciate  any feedback of this

Answer (score 1):

The units in SceneKit ARE already meters. So you will have to adjust the input accordingly, i.e. scale by 1000.